# Change the selected text on iframe cross browsers

Tags: javascript, text, replace, selection

How can i change the selected text on editable iframe by js?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to include some Javascript on the page you're loading into the iframe. You can't do it from the 'outside', if that's what you're asking.

If, however, you're loading the iframe from the same domain, you can call functions on Javascript that's already in the iframe. If you're loading an iframe from another domain, though, you'd run into the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

If you're interested in dynamically populating an iframe, you may be interested in something like this:

```
var iframe = createIframe('iframe0', 300, 300);
if (iframe) {
    var iframeDoc;
    if (iframe.contentDocument) {
        iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument;
    }
    else if (iframe.contentWindow) {
        iframeDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
    }
    else if (window.frames[iframe.name]) {
        iframeDoc = window.frames[iframe.name].document;
    }
    if (iframeDoc) {
        iframeDoc.open();
        iframeDoc.write('<html><body><p>Awesomeness for all.<\/p><\/body><\/html>');
        iframeDoc.close();
    }
}​
```

*(borrowed from [here](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/94228-iframe-dynamic-create-populate-immediately))*

There's a lot of stuff out there about this sort of thing. It's a pretty involved topic and hard to give a good answer to. I'd recommend attempting to write your editor on your own, then coming back here if/when you run into any problems. That way, you can provide a specific question to which a specific solution is possible. Best of luck!

Comment: The iframe doesnt have a "src" attr, he is edit able (Im making an editor)

Comment: Unless you're making an editor for learning purposes, I'd suggest using TinyMCE. However, edited my answer.